# How does zoom work in android.webkit.WebView?

Tags: android, webview, zooming, scale

I tried studied the WebView source for quite a long time, and I can't understand how the zoom feature is implemented.

- The Height and Width of the View is always the same,
- canvas width and height are always =0,
- the only thing which changes is getScale()

Maybe someone can explain, how zoom is implemented in WebView if not by increasing the view?

Answer (score 0):

I didn´t look at the code, but I guess it´s a canvas, that´s scaled up and down.

how do you access the canvas' height and width?

Comment: I save a pointer to canvas when onDraw happens.
Canvas' width and height are always as 0.

Comment: Google can provides code for Canvas here: 
http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/graphics/java/android/graphics/Canvas.java&q=canvas&exact_package=git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/frameworks/base.git&type=cs